# How can i develope subpages in surveys?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say that i want to create a survey page on the web i wold like to make pages each contain number of questions but i have i problem.
I don't want to create about 3 or 4 separated pages and use **Next Button** that **href** another page.
I am running out of ideas about how can i implement that.

```
<pre> <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">   </script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
        });
    })

});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script> 
    function show() { 
    if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='none') { 
        document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='block'; 
    } 
    return false;
} 
function hide() { 
    if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='block') { 
        document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='none'; 
    } 
    return false;
}   
 </script> 


  <div id="opener"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick="return show();">click here</a></div> 
   <div id="benefits" style="display:none;">some input in here plus the close button 
       <div id="upbutton"><a onclick="return hide();">click here</a></div> 
  </div> 
 </body> 
 </html> <code>
```

Comment: [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) may help you! Go throgh it!

Comment: you can try out for ajax where onclick of next button function will be called in which ajax request will be made.

these ajax response will be with the question fetched from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may consider using a database like mySQL with a questions table, that would allow you to load them into a page dynamically. This would allow you to make a page template and just dynamically request the page id from the questions table to load all question that belong to that "page".

if you don't have access to php or mysql, and want to stick with jquery/javascript, you might consider setting up a json database and just using ajax to load in the questions.